# Removing double quotes in a CSV with delimeter inside

Tags: shell, unix, awk

```
awk -F , '{if ($2 ~ /^".*"$/) $2 = substr($2, 2, length($2)-2); {gsub(/""/, "", $2);} print $2;}' sample.csv
```

I have devloped the above `awk` to remove double quotes in 2nd column. the `awk` was working fine for the below content

sample.csv

```
file,"file2",file3
```

output of sample.csv with above `awk`

```
file,file2,file3
```

But the `awk` is not working for the below scenario

sample1.csv

```
file,"fil,e2",file3
```

output of sample1.txt  with above `awk`

```
file,"fil,e2",file3
```

Required output of sample1.txt

```
file,file2,file3
```

I know the issue is because of comma separator inside the Double quotes, is there any way to skip this?

I want to remove double quotes on 2nd column(the source may contain multiple comma(`,`) inside the double quotes like `"fi,l,e2`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat file
file,"file2",file3,"a,b,c","d,e"

$ awk -F'"' -v OFS= '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/,"",$i)}1' file
file,file2,file3,abc,de
```

Comment: +1 Very nice.  Note that this probably does the wrong thing on input of the form `file,"file\"containing\"quotes",...`, but that's another issue altogether.

Comment: Yup, there's all sorts of caveats, not least of which is fields containing newlines, so hopefully the OP has posted some TRULY representative sample input for his data. If he hasn't then all bets are off.